# Vuetify Table - rendering column value based on a API response

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, axios, vue-component

[image]

I have this simple function

```
displayAttributeNameBasedOnId(id) {

    axios.defaults.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
    let data = {
        $root: 'vc_rule_attribute',
        op: 'read',
        brand: localStorage.getItem('brandCode'),
        selection: {
            filters: ['id:' + id]
        },
        _SESSION: localStorage.getItem('session')
    }
    axios.post(window.MTS_URL, data).then((response) => {
        return response.data.rule_attributes[0].name
    })
},
```

It will displayAttributeNameBasedOnId.

I think I am facing race condition issue. I can see the result of the console.log(), but It's not displaying in the table.

```
<td>{{ displayAttributeNameBasedOnId(item.attribute_id) }}</td>
```

In my table, I call that function.

How can I make sure to wait for the axios to be done ?

---

## Try #2

```
async displayAttributeNameBasedOnId(id) {
        console.log('displayAttributeNameBasedOnId', id)

        axios.defaults.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
        let data = {
            $root: 'vc_rule_attribute',
            op: 'read',
            brand: localStorage.getItem('brandCode'),
            selection: {
                filters: ['id:' + id]
            },
            _SESSION: localStorage.getItem('session')
        }
        await axios.post(window.MTS_URL, data).then((response) => {
            console.log('response.data', response.data)
            return response.data.rule_attributes[0].name
        })
    },
```

I got

[image]

Answer (score 0):

My solution is to get attributeNames for ids in the table on `mounted` or `created` hook, and then get attributeName for specific id in `methods` based on attributeNames

Comment: mounted, and created, I don't know what is the id yet. They created on the fly, I will show UI.

Comment: Calling `displayAttributeNameBasedOnId` on each row means number of ajax calls which is not a good way.
If you don't have ids on `created` or `mounted`, I would send ajax request to get attributeNames right after we get Ids

Comment: I have access to that in the memory, how can I filter an object base on the property atched ?

Comment: You can declare `attributeNames` as an empty object and after each ajax call completed, you can assign `name` to `attributeNames` for each id.
You can then use `attributeNames` in the template

Answer (score 0):

I think your function `displayAttributeNameBasedOnId` returns nothing
on your try #2 can you add a return statement:

```
  return await axios.post(window.MTS_URL, data).then((response) => {
```

let us know if it worked !